# Set folder and file as readonly for everyone with cmd line

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions

Our build system downloads tests data folders that are then used for running tests. Some devs have the bad habit of writing inside these folders, which means the second execution of a test is not necessarily identical to the first one.

Once downloaded, I want to set the permission as readonly for everyone on that folder. I tried

```
icacls D:\Data\Tests /grant:r Everyone:R /T
```

But it is overided by existing groups like Authenticated Users. I also tried with

```
icacls D:\Data\Tests /grant:r %userdomain%\%username%:R
```

But I can still create files and folders in the test folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to remove or block inheritance on the folder.

> /inheritance:e|d|r
> e - enables inheritance
> d - disables inheritance and copy the ACEs
> r - remove all inherited ACEs